# GetX - Passing Values Across ViewModels

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm new to `Getx` & I'm trying to pass three `String` variables created in `FirstViewModel` into `SecondViewModel` how do I achieve this ?

```
class FirstViewModel extends GetxController with StateMixin<List<PhotoModel>> {...}
```

```
class SecondViewModel extends GetxController {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second viewmodel:

```
class SecondViewModel extends GetxController {
     final FirstViewModel firstViewModel = Get.find();

     final firstString = Rxn<String>();
     
     final photoModels = <PhotoModel>[].obs;


   @override
   onInit(){
          firstString.value = firstViewModel.firstString.value; // If you are using Rx

          photoModels.assignAll(firstViewModel.state); // Get the state from `StateMixin`

 }
```

Comment: FirstViewModel" not found. You need to call "Get.put(FirstViewModel)